# PHP Rabbit MQ Read Specific Message from single Queue

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I need a help to consume a specific value in my queue, I'm following the example from rabbitMQ website: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-php.html

basically I will have an exchange (topic) with some routing keys, each routing key points towards to a queue.

Exchange: SAC

Queue = sac-yami

[image]

And a Need to read the specific value ex:

Queue sac-yami have 3 records,

- "101"
- "102"
- "103"

I was inserted by this way..

- php emit_log_topic.php "protocol.101" "101"
- php emit_log_topic.php "protocol.102" "102"
- php emit_log_topic.php "protocol.103" "103"

I need to remove 103 from queue, how I do that?

here's my code: to emit..

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$exchange = "sac";
$queue = "sac-yami";
$type = 'topic';
$message = implode(' ', array_slice($argv, 2));

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('MYHOST', PORT, 'USER', 'PASS','/');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$routing_key = isset($argv[1]) && !empty($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : 'anonymous.info';
$channel->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);
$channel->exchange_declare($exchange, $type, false, true, false);
$channel->queue_bind($queue, $exchange, $routing_key);

$msg = new AMQPMessage($message);
$return = $channel->basic_publish($msg, $exchange, $routing_key);
$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

and to read:

```
$rabbit->connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($rabbit->host, $rabbit->port, $rabbit->user, $rabbit->pass, $rabbit->vhost);
$rabbit->channel = $rabbit->connection->channel();

$rabbit->channel->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);
$rabbit->channel->exchange_declare($queue, 'topic', false, true, false);
$rabbit->channel->queue_bind($queue, $routingKey);
$rabbit->channel->basic_consume($queue, $consumerTag, false, false, false, false, array($rabbit, 'processMessage'));

    function processMessage($message)
        {
            $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    print_r($message);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all three messages are routed to the same queue (`sac-yami`), you must consume from that queue to read the messages. They will be delivered in the order in which they were published - 101, 102 and 103. There is no way to read message 103 before the other two.